# Convert a Rhodes PropertyBag Model to JSON

Tags: json, rhomobile, rhodes

I have a Rhodes (RhoMobile) PropertyBag Model that I would like to convert to JSON string.  I tried @model_instance.to_json but it does not appear that method exists.  I would like to then take the JSON string and submit it to a RESTful service.  Any assistance is much appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel so silly. I did not realize the json gem is not automatically included. All I had to do was require 'json' at the top of the controller file and call @model_name.to_json. I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I think first of all you need to convert the model to meta data, Meta data is defined in a source adapter by implementing an adapter method `metadata` that returns a JSON structure. then you can use `yourmodelname.metadata('foo' => 'bar' }.to_json` then it will convert your database into json. This is basically done with FixedSchema, not sure about the PropertyBag.

http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/rhom

http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhoconnect/metadata

Comment: Thank you, Dave. I appreciate the response. I found the solution on my own. Please see my answer.